# Angular-CLI Serve with Lint Watch

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tslint

Is there any way to run `ng lint` while watching for file changes during `ng serve`? To encourage best practices according to the Angular 2 Style Guide our CI tool runs `ng lint` during the build process and it isn't always a developers first thought to run lint before submitting a pull request.

Is it possible to customize what `ng serve` does or has anyone figured out a way to include running lint as part of the recompilation process? If not, I'd also be interested in knowing whether others have any opinions on whether this is a good idea or not and why.

Comment: No, currently, there is no such an option. However, tslint is integrated into many popular IDE and Editors. You can maybe update the script tag in package.json to run parallel tasks (npm run start - in script tag you have "start":"ng serve && ng lint" -> in this case linting is automatically started during startup)

Comment: There is a work-around, see my answer below. You just need to run both `ng serve` and `npm run lint:watch` in different terminals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define an additional npm script with a watch using nodemon for this.

1. Install nodemon npm package globally (`npm i -g nodemon`) or in your project (`npm i --save-dev nodemon`)
2. Define the npm script in package.json (under `"scripts"`): `

   `"lint:watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm run lint || exit 1\" --ext ts,html,scss"`
3. Run `npm run lint:watch`

You can change the `--ext ts,html,scss,json` to whatever file extensions you want to cause lint to restart. For further documentation of nodemon, see https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon

Comment: Edited: you need to add "`|| exit 1`" to the end of the script given in `--exec` because npm will return exit code 2 on lint errors which breaks nodemon's watch.