# How to run ts-lint when before compiling in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tslint

when running `ng serve` the angular cli watches for changes and recompiles the project. For me it would be helpful if `ng lint` could be run on a filechange as well. Of course it would be gread if only the changed file gets checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an additional npm script with a watch using nodemon for this.

Install nodemon npm package globally `npm i -g nodemon` or in your project `npm i --save-dev nodemon`
Define the npm script in package.json (under "scripts"): `

`"lint:watch": "nodemon --exec \"npm run lint || exit 1\" --ext ts,html,scss"`

Define another script `"serve-lint": "npm run serve && npm run lint:watch"`

Run `npm run serve-lint`

[Angular-CLI Serve with Lint Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448771/angular-cli-serve-with-lint-watch)