# Is possible to run lint while angular is generating Browser application bundle?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-scripts

I would like to check if there are lint errors while angular is generating Browser application bundle and fail if there are errors.

Is that possible? I have used demon to create a watch but thats not what i am looking for... [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448771/angular-cli-serve-with-lint-watch?rq=1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run npm script in parralel using `&` operator. Refer to [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel) for more information.